# Why is my function which is supposed to calculate remaining HP instead returning the same number as the damage done

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and practicing by making a simple game. So far it's just running automatically. What I want is for the attacked characters HP being reduced by the attacking character's damage, but what happens is that it always says the attacked character's HP is equal to the damage done. So if character X does 5 damage, it will say character Y's remaining HP is 5. I've gone through the lines of code over and over but still cannot seem to see where the issue is.

```
class Character:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        if self.name == "Warrior":
            self.hp = 10
            self.attack = 3
            self.defence = 2
            self.speed = 1
        elif self.name == "Rogue":
            self.hp = 7
            self.attack = 3
            self.defence = 1
            self.speed = 5
```

It seems like the error is happening somewhere in the below actionResult() function.

```
import random
from Character import Character

class Battle:

    def __init__(self):
        self.combatant_one = Character("Warrior")
        self.combatant_two = Character("Rogue")
        self.name_one = self.combatant_one.get_name()
        self.name_two = self.combatant_two.get_name()
        self.speed_one = self.combatant_one.get_speed()
        self.speed_two = self.combatant_two.get_speed()
        self.attack_one = self.combatant_one.get_attack()
        self.attack_two = self.combatant_two.get_attack()
        self.defence_one = self.combatant_one.get_defence()
        self.defence_two = self.combatant_two.get_defence()
        self.hp_one = self.combatant_one.get_hp()
        self.hp_two = self.combatant_two.get_hp()
        self.battle_finished = False


    def whoGoesFirst (self):
        print(self.speed_one)
        print(self.speed_two)
        speed_one = self.speed_one + random.randint(1, 10)
        speed_two = self.speed_two + random.randint(1, 10)
        if speed_one == speed_two:
            while (speed_one == speed_two):
                speed_one = self.speed_one + random.randint(1, 10)
                speed_two = self.speed_two + random.randint(1, 10)
        if speed_one > speed_two:
            print(self.name_one + " goes first.")
            return self.name_one
        else:
            print(self.name_two + " goes first.")
            return self.name_two


    def characterAction(self, character):
        if character == "Warrior":
            attack = self.attack_one + random.randint(1, 3)
            defence = self.defence_two
            target_hp = self.hp_two
        elif character == "Rogue":
            attack = self.attack_two + random.randint(1, 3)
            defence = self.defence_one
            target_hp = self.hp_one
        damage = attack - defence
        if damage <= 0:
            damage = 1
        print(character + " attacks for " + str(damage) + " damage.")
        attacked_hp = target_hp - damage
        if attacked_hp <= 0:
            attacked_hp = 0
        return attacked_hp


    def actionResult(self, attackingChar, attacked_hp):
        if attackingChar == "Rogue":
            self.hp_one = self.hp_one - attacked_hp
            if attacked_hp > 0:
                print(self.name_one + " has " + str(self.hp_one) + " health remaining.")
            else:
                print(self.name_one + " has 0 HP, he dies.")
                self.battle_finished = True
        elif attackingChar == "Warrior":
            self.hp_two = self.hp_two - attacked_hp
            if attacked_hp > 0:
                print(self.name_two + " has " + str(self.hp_two) + " health remaining.")
            else:
                print(self.name_two + " has 0 HP, he dies.")
                self.battle_finished = True


battle = Battle()
firstMover = battle.whoGoesFirst()
action = battle.characterAction(firstMover)
battle.actionResult(firstMover, action)
```

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Comment: Welcome to [so]). While it is beneficial to show your work effort, it is counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [mre] for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are calculating the current HP minus damage to get remaining HP:

```
attacked_hp = target_hp - damage
if attacked_hp <= 0:
    attacked_hp = 0
    return attacked_hp
```

Then you use this attacked_hp as input here:

```
def actionResult(self, attackingChar, attacked_hp):
    if attackingChar == "Rogue":
        self.hp_one = self.hp_one - attacked_hp
    ...
```

So you subtract this remaining HP from the current HP. The difference that is the result here then is just the damage again (`(HP - (HP - damage)) = damage`).

So what you need to do is calculate the remaining HP just once (instead of twice and mixing the results).